# uwp MostRecentlyUsedList is reverse everytime I access it

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, storage, windows-10-universal

I have a "History" page in my app which shows **mostRecentlyUsedList** so on that page I get all the items in it like following.

```
foreach (var entry in StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Entries)
        {
            var file = await StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.GetFileAsync(entry.Token);
        }
```

I am able to get all files, but everytime I comeback to this back or navigate to it again, I get the list in reverse.

**first access** items from 1 to 25 will be shown ( 1st item will be shown 1st )
**2nd access** items from 25 to 1 will be shown ( last item s shown first )
**3rd access** again items from 1 to 25 are shown

and so on...

the **QuickAccess** of **FileExplorer** shown them in order always, ( the most recently used item is shown at the top. this is how I want to show them in my app as well.

Comment: It's mabye because you access the files and therefore the list ist modified. Could store the filenames and tokens in your app. So getting the tokens would be enough to get the filenames? Or check if the list ist already populated; if so skip repopulating

Comment: I think you are right @thezapper accesing them changes the list. I have to figure out a way to sync it with app database, because I also need the thumbnails of those files. but thnks, and add this as answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetFileAsync(token) is accessing the files and therefore the timestamp is modified. You need to store need metadata in your appfolder and access MostRecentlyUsedList only once